# Is it possible to adjust contrast of ccsprite in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm trying to give ccsprite blink effect by adjusting brightness.
so I need to adjust contrast of ccsprite.
How to do that?

```
CCSprite* ccs_sprite = CCSprite::create("button.png");
ccs_sprite->setPosition(ccp(500, 500));
ccs_sprite->setContrast()???

addChild(ccs_sprite);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a blink effect by adjusting the opacity of the sprite with the `setOpacity` method and alternatively using the `CCFadeIn`, `CCFadeOut` and `CCFadeTo` actions.

**Edit:**

There is also the `CCTintTo` and `CCTintBy` actions that will adjust the RGB colors of the node.

Comment: I'd like to give blink effect by adjusting more brightness.

Comment: CCTintTo and CCTintBy is beautiful.

Comment: You can also have a look at the blending function (CCSprite::setBlendFunc()). Available [blend modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes)

Answer (score 0):

You can visit here for detail reference about classes in cocos2d-x
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/d4/de7/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_sprite.html